# JavaScript addEventListener use external JavaScript file

Tags: javascript

So I have this page which is setup with a Bootstrap template.

What I would like to do is to use an external JavaScript-file as such: `drive:\myfolder\mysubfolder\myexternaljavascriptfile.js`. The `<script>` tag is located just before the `</body>` tag.

The Bootstrap-javafiles are in the `<head>` section. Also tried placing it in the `<body>` section.

So this is what I have now.

```
<script>
const element = document.getElementById("hitme");
element.addEventListener("click", myfunc); 
</script>
```

also tried using `myfunc()` to no avail.

I want `myfunc` to use my external JavaScript file

It works if I use it in the same `<script>` tag in the HTML doc but that is not what I want.

Also, it does work if I use `<button onclick("Myfunc")>Hit Me</button>` but I reckon this is the old way using the click-event etc.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Currently you've provided some fragments of code, with some of the dependencies missing, only very vague descriptions of how they fit together, and some parts (the last for example) which have clear errors but which you claim works. You need to provide a tested demonstration.

Answer (score -1):

Put the js file in the same folder as your index.html file and link it to HTML with script tag `<script href="script,js" defer><script>` defer attribute load the js file after HTML CSS done loading